# TFS security

Tags: security, tfs

Anyone have information on hardening/configuring TFS for secure environments?

Comment: I hope TFS = Team Foundation Server or maybe I'm not interested after all... I hate it, but we're struck using it here.

Comment: @Andrew Flanagan: TFS properly setup works well. We use it very effectively. Check out TFS sidekicks: http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Comment: Not strictly programming related, but a good question nonetheless.

Comment: Sure its programming related! TFS is a programming tool, after all... :-)

Comment: Mitch is right, but surely this is a better site than ServerFault

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TFS uses windows authentication, so it's as secure as your network is. I suggest you also check out resources on hardening network security.

[Team Foundation Server Security Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253184(VS.80).aspx)

[Team Foundation Server Security Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252473(VS.80).aspx)

[Team Foundation Server Security for Users and Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252512(VS.80).aspx)

[Securing Team Foundation Server with HTTPS and Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395265(VS.80).aspx)

[Troubleshooting Team Foundation Server Permissions and Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400712.aspx)

If you haven't looked at it already, TFS comes with a command line security tool, [TFSSecurity.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252504.aspx)